# Upload a Tempfile to Carrierwave in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create a Tempfile using some user-inputted information in one of my models:

```
after_create :form_to_csv

def form_to_csv
  temp_file = Tempfile.new('test_temp.csv', encoding: 'utf-8')

  begin
    self.input_data.split('\n').each do |line|
      temp_file.write line
    end

    temp_file.rewind
    self.build_input_data_file(file: Rails.root.join("temp_file.path}").open)
  ensure
    temp_file.close
    temp_file.unlink
  end
end
```

The form data is stored in the `input_data` field as text. I get to write my data to the Tempfile successfully but attaching it to the model is cumbersome - I keep trying to attach `nil` to my model. My main problem is that the file I generate has a path like:

```
/var/folders/jw/7pjlw_212qd3s4ddfj1zvnpr0000gn/T/test_temp.csv20170502-78762-1eh23ml
```

and it won't work with Rails.root.join and with the attachment method propose in CarrierWave docs [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-%22Upload%22-from-a-local-file) (Upload from a local file).

Comment: Did you try assigning the `temp_fie` object directly to the `file` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake was that I tried to assign a .csv extension within the filename parameter of the Tempfile object. Instead I needed to pass an array like this:

```
def form_to_csv
  temp_file = Tempfile.new(['test_temp', '.csv'], encoding: 'utf-8')

  begin
    self.input_data.split('\n').each do |line|
      temp_file.write line
    end

    temp_file.rewind

    self.build_input_data_file(file: Rails.root.join(temp_file.path).open)
  ensure
    temp_file.close
    temp_file.unlink
  end
end
```